# Google Play Billing - Check the status of Subscription

Tags: android, play-billing-library

On tap of button, I'm directly calling launchPurchase() just like below

```
btn_subcription.setOnClickListener {
    launchPurchase()
}
```

What I Want ?

1. First of all, check the status of subscription, If already subscribed then just show a toast "Already purchased"
2. Otherwise call launchPurchase() function to purchase Subscription

Click [here](https://github.com/mightyfrog/Play-Billing-Library-Sample-for-Kotlin/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/codelab/sample/MainActivity.kt) to see full code

Thanks

Comment: you can add a `if-else` condition to do that work

Comment: I know that, but don't know what exactly to write... to check the status of subscription in If condition

Comment: As i can see in your code you can get a status code for the purchase. So, you can check for that code and implement your condition

Comment: I'm new to this... so not getting exactly what to write ?